# Detecting When Javascript is Done Executing

Tags: javascript, ajax

Is there an event in javascript that I could bind some sort of listener to that will tell me when all javascript/jQuery/Ajax is done executing on the page?  The page will not be loading/unloading/reloading, etc between the time the execution begins and the time that I need the listener to "listen", so those events don't work.  The page literally is not doing anything.  The button is clicked and some javascript functions fire which contain Ajax calls to web services.  After all have finished, I want to change window.location.  But window.location is changing before the web services have finished in my case.

Currently using setTimeout to achieve this, but as sometimes the code needs more time to run than normal, sometimes the window.location is firing before all the other javascript has finished.  Simply put

```
<input type = "button"... onclick="doThis();";

function doThis() {
   try{
      //Contains AJAX calls to web services which is mainly what screws up my timing since it may still be trying to execute stuff when the redirect statement happens
      }
   catch (e) {
      }
  //Currently doing setTimeout(redirect, 10000);
  //Would like to simply detect when all of the above is done and then redirect.  
}
```

Edit:  Left out a crucial piece of info.  The AJAX calls are in a for loop.  The use of variables and success callbacks hasn't been working so well for me as by the time my success callback is executing, my variables have taken on new values in the for loop.

Comment: **callbacks** are your friends ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using `jQuery.ajax`, it sounds like you're looking for  [ajaxStop](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/).

Comment: This works GREAT!!!  Only thing I'm unsure of is how do I "unbind" the ajaxStop request in the event of some sort of error during processing the ajax request?   Even if one of my error callbacks returns, wouldn't that still constitute ajaxStop and the event fires anyway?

Comment: @user877442 - `$("#wtv").unbind("ajaxStop");`... I think.

Answer (score 5):

What you are trying to achieve is a classical concurrent programming problem. It is solved by the use of a [barrier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrier_%28computer_science%29).

To put it simply, you need to:

1. Count how many calls you've done.
2. Set a callback on all AJAX completion events.
3. Make that callback decrement the number of calls.
4. The callback checks whether the number of calls has reached zero or not. If yes, then your final code (here, `redirect`) is called.

The actual implementation is left as an exercise to the reader  :)

Hint: embed AJAX calls into a function that handles all counter incrementation and callback setting.

Comment: So if I understand you, I would use a variable to detect when my last call to ajax is indeed my last call to ajax, and then set my redirect to occur during the success portion of that ajax call?

Comment: Almost: you are using the variable to detect not when the last call is the last call, but when the last _completion_ is the last completion. The difference lies in the fact that you can't know if your last call will complete last, and that changes a lot. And then, indeed, you set your redirect to occur when all calls have `completed`. Please also note you should not use the "success portion" but the `complete` callback, to avoid blocking if one of the calls failed. Unless that's expected behavior, of course.

Comment: Ohhhh. I see. I am 100% self taught, so I'm not super great with all this yet.  I'll look at using the ajax complete event and get back to you.  Thanks so much!

Comment: ajaxComplete is great.  But ajaxStop detects when all AJAX is done so I don't even have to worry about detecting whether or not it is my last completion.  $("#button").ajaxStop(redirect).

Comment: Ok, could you then please specify "jQuery" in the question title and tags? And remember to specify it in your further questions  :)

Answer (score 3):

What I do:

- Create a variable that represents the number of outstanding AJAX calls.
- Before making an AJAX call, increment the variable.
- At the end of the code that completes an AJAX call, call a function (e.g. ajaxComplete).
- ajaxComplete should decrement the count.  When it reaches zero, you know all your calls are complete.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try using something like the [Underscore library](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/)'s [`after`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#after) function in the callbacks?

```
var done = _.after(3, function() {
    window.location = 'http://example.com';
});

$.ajax({
  url: '/tic',
  success: function() {
    done();
  }
});
$.ajax({
  url: '/tac',
  success: function() {
    done();
  }
});
$.ajax({
  url: '/toe',
  success: function( data ) {
    done();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check for the response from AJAX call, and only in that response do redirect. This way you will avoid doing redirect while AJAX was still executing.